# pandas: replicating an excel formula in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

What i have is a dataframe like:

```
   total_sum  pid
   5          2
   1          2
   6          7
   3          7
   1          7
   1          7
   0          7
   5         10
   1         10
   1         10
```

What I want is another column `pos` like:

```
   total_sum  pid    pos
   5          2      1
   1          2      2 
   6          7      1
   3          7      2
   1          7      3
   1          7      3
   0          7      4
   5         10      1
   1         10      2
   1         10      2
```

The logic behind is:

The initial `pos` value for new `pid` is `1`.

If `pid` does not change but the `total_sum` changes, the value for `pos` is incremented by 1 (example first two rows) else the value for `pos` is the previous value (example last two rows).

What i tried:

```
 df['pos'] = 1
 df['pos'] = np.where(((df.pid.diff(-1)) == 0 & (df.total_sum.diff(-1) == 0)),
                                                     df.pos, (np.where(df.total_sum.diff(1) < 1, df.pos + 1, df.pos )))
```

Currently, I am doing it in an excel sheet, where I initially write 1 manually in the first column of `pos` and then write the formula in second cell of `pos`:

```
=IF(A3<>A2,1,IF(B3=B2,C2,C2+1))
```

Comment: Shouldnt the 5th and 6th rows have the same `pos` value?

Comment: Fixed, apologies,. I have been going bonkers over getting this done. hence had a slight typo'ed result pasted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Explanation**:

Doing `groupby` on `pid` to group the same `pid` into separate groups. On each group, apply these following operations:

_ Call `diff` on each group. `diff` returns integers or `NaN` indicate the differences between 2 consecutive rows. First row of each group has no previous row, so `diff` always returns `NaN` for first row of each group :

```
df.groupby('pid').total_sum.transform(lambda x: x.diff()

Out[120]:
0    NaN
1   -4.0
2    NaN
3   -3.0
4   -2.0
5    0.0
6   -1.0
7    NaN
8   -4.0
9    0.0
Name: total_sum, dtype: float64
```

_ `ne` checks to see if any value is not `0`. It returns `True` on not `0`

```
df.groupby('pid').total_sum.transform(lambda x: x.diff().ne(0))

Out[121]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4     True
5    False
6     True
7     True
8     True
9    False
Name: total_sum, dtype: bool
```

_ `cumsum` is cumulative sum which successively adds each rows. In Python, `True` is interpreted as `1` and `False` interpreted as `0`. The 1st of each group is always `True`, so `cumsum` is always starting from `1` and adding up each rows to get the desired output.

```
df.groupby('pid').total_sum.transform(lambda x: x.diff().ne(0).cumsum())

Out[122]:
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    2
4    3
5    3
6    4
7    1
8    2
9    2
Name: total_sum, dtype: int32
```

---

Chain all commands to one-liner as follows:

```
df['pos'] = df.groupby('pid').total_sum.transform(lambda x: x.diff().ne(0).cumsum())

Out[99]:
   total_sum  pid  pos
0          5    2    1
1          1    2    2
2          6    7    1
3          3    7    2
4          1    7    3
5          1    7    3
6          0    7    4
7          5   10    1
8          1   10    2
9          1   10    2
```

Comment: What is `cumsum()` doing? Could you explain this a little? I want to understand it rather than just getting it done

Comment: sure, give me a few minutes :)

Comment: @LeeKan: I added step-by-step explanation.